# Performing sql statement wit CTE using mysql c api

Tags: mysql, c

I'm changing sql server query into mysql syntax. I'm using mysql c api. If I try to execute my query in mysql terminal all works, but not with mysql_query function. This is my query:

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ; WITH RECURSIVE CTE  AS ( SELECT Id, ParentId, UserId, (select UserId from user where Id=S.ParentId) as ParentUserName, 1 AS Level FROM user S where ParentId = -1 or ISNULL(ParentId) UNION ALL SELECT child.Id, child.ParentId, child.UserId, (select UserId from user where Id=child.ParentId) as ParentUserName,  Level + 1 AS Level FROM user child INNER JOIN CTE ON  child.ParentId = CTE.Id)  SELECT distinct * FROM CTE order by Level,Id; commit;
```

And this is my sql statement:

```
std::string query = "SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ; WITH RECURSIVE CTE  AS ( SELECT Id, ParentId, UserId, (select UserId from user where Id=S.ParentId) as ParentUserName, ";
query += "1 AS Level FROM user S where ParentId = -1 or ISNULL(ParentId) UNION ALL SELECT child.Id, child.ParentId, child.UserId, (select UserId from user where Id = child.ParentId) as ParentUserName, ";
query+="Level + 1 AS Level FROM user child INNER JOIN CTE ON  child.ParentId = CTE.Id)  SELECT distinct* FROM CTE order by Level, Id; commit; ";

MYSQL_RES*=mysql_query(conn, query);
mysql_store_result(conn);

if (!res)
{
    printf("Error while execution query %s\n", mysql_error(my));

}
```

Comment: Did you get any errors ? If yes can you share it please ?

Comment: Error while execution query. You have an error in your sql syntax..... near  'WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS (select Id, ParentId, UserId, (select UserId from user w' at line 1

Comment: I never used the mysql c api, but it seems like your query contains two statements, could you tried executing the first one, and then the second one ?

Comment: Also make sure you are using MySQL 8 (earlier versions do not support ctes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I was able to perform my query using a bash script and redirecting output in my c++ function:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -u root -pPassword <<EOF
USE mydb;
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ; WITH RECURSIVE 
CTE  AS ( SELECT Id, ParentId, UserId, (select UserId from user where 
Id=S.ParentId) as ParentUserName, 1 AS Level FROM user S where ParentId = 
-1 or ISNULL(ParentId) UNION ALL SELECT child.Id, child.ParentId, 
child.UserId, (select UserId from user where Id=child.ParentId) as 
ParentUserName,  Level + 1 AS Level FROM user child INNER JOIN CTE ON  
child.ParentId = CTE.Id)  SELECT distinct * FROM CTE order by Level,Id; 
commit;

EOF
```

And in my code I got all table fields doing:

```
FILE* script;
char line[250];
script = popen("./query.sh", "r");

std::vector<std::string> vs;
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), script))
{

    
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    std::string token;
    while(std::getline(iss,token,'\t'))
    
    vs.push_back(token);
        

}
```